# Black screen and "the system is running in low graphics mode" while loading Ubuntu from USB stick

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I've just built a new PC. I've downloaded a USB boot installer for Ubuntu 12.04.

When I power on the PC with the stick in, it all seems to start off well. It gives me the option to install Ubuntu which I choose.

It starts to work, but then just hangs on a black screen. If it leave it even longer, it will say something about the system needing to run in low graphics mode.

How can I fix this?

I have no CD drive on my build so I need to have an OS via USB.

Comment: Potentially related cross-network post: [How do I fix "The system is running in low graphics mode"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/497313)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this link might give you some hints on how to boot into the text mode installer.
https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/boot-parms.html. Also, you might want to verify that the graphics driver for your video card is supported.

Comment: My graphics card is a HD7770. CPU is an i5. I can't imagine there's anything wrong with the set-up? Kind of annoying how hard this is proving to be! After the hassle of building it (my first time) I assumed this installing an OS would be simple bit!!

Comment: So, does it actual boot into Ubuntu?

Comment: I put the USB in, it recognises the boot files as it comes up with a menu offering me the choice to install, continue without installing, etc. But whatever I do, it just hangs on the black screen...

Comment: Sorry my friend, it took me a while but this is the document I was looking for. This will help ya. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions. Go to the section on Changing the CD Boot Option Configuration Line and play with the vga settings.